# I can't install (boot-repair) on my Unbunt 12.04 LiveCD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, apt, grub2

I had a Linux Mint 17 on my PC. Then I installed Windows 10. I lost the Grub. While recovering it I've used the following steps:

- Got my Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD [Because I've lost my Linux Mint 17 LiveCD]
- Added the repository for boot-repair using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`.
- Updated the repository using `sudo apt-get update`
- Then, I typed the installation command `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`.

The problem I've got the following response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

Any help I have to recover the Linux Mint as soon as possible

Comment: Most likely because `yannbuntu/boot-repair` doesn't support 12.04.

Comment: Once you install Windows, it overwrites whatever other OS was there on the disk , so I would suggest you reinstall Mint if you really want to use that. You may also look into some data recovery tools, but i doubt they will help, as disk is overwritten.  That's one point. Second point, you're on the site for **Ubuntu** , we don't fix Linux Mint here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just wanted an answer for my issue because my future is based on it now. The point is I am on the edge I am just looking for answer. And as I believe Linux Mint is based on Debian like Ubuntu and saying Linux is saying Free like in Freedom. Sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: I suppose a `grub-install /dev/sd×` would fix it (`×` being the disk partition to which you installed Mint).

Comment: @BharadwajRaju It is saying: Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Comment: If from live installer, you first have to mount partition with install (and /boot if separate partition) and then install grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System Simple commands above are to reinstall from within a working system or from within system to install to another MBR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Linux Mint 18 Beta and installed the boot-repair everything works fine.